# Calculating $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} {(x-1)^4 y^2 \over (x-1)^8 + y^4 }$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} {(x-1)^4 y^2 \over (x-1)^8 + y^4 }$  doesn't exist, because the limit is not the same for different trajectories:  For $ y=x-1,  L = 0 $. And for $y=(x-1)^2, L= 1/2 $

But before I knew this, I asked myself if I could find a function $g(x,y)$ such that

$ 0 \le {(x-1)^4 y^2 \over (x-1)^8 + y^4 } \le g(x,y) $
 whose limit existed and was 0. And I couldn't. Maybe it is a dumb question, but, how do I now that $g$ does not exist? Is it possible to know this?

Comment: If $g$ existed, then the limit of $g$ would be 0 for $y=(x-1)^2$. But in this case, the limit of the middle term is 1/2, so $g$ could not go to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We try to claim that there exists a function $g$ such that

$$0\leq\text{your function}\leq g(x,y)\text{ and}\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)=0,$$ then by squeeze theorem:
 $$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\text{your function}=0, \rightarrow\leftarrow.$$ This is a contradiction since you've proven that the limit doesn't exist. Therefore there is not such $g$.